# PHP constructors and static functions

Tags: php, constructor, static-functions

I'm a bit confused on how constructors work in PHP.

I have a class with a constructor which gets called when I instantiate a new object.

```
$foo = new Foo($args);
```

`__construct($params)` is called in the class `Foo` and it executes the appropriate initialization code.

However when I use the class to call a static function, the constructor is called again.

```
$bar = Foo::some_function(); //runs the constructor from Foo
```

This causes the constructor to execute, running the object initialization code that I intended only for when I create a new `Foo` object.

Am I missing the point of how constructors work? Or is there a way to prevent `__construct()` from executing when I use the class to make static function calls?

Should I use a "factory" function instead to do the object initialization? If so, what's the point of the constructor then?

::EDIT::
I have a form where users can upload photos to an album (create_photo.php) and an area where they can view the album (view_photos.php). Upon form submit:

```
$photo = new Photo($_FILES['photo'], $_POST['arg1'], ect..);
```

The Photo constructor creates and saves the photo. However in view_photo.php, when I call:

```
$photo = Photo::find_by_id($_POST['id']) //user-defined function to query database
```

This is causing Photo's constructor to run!

Comment: That can't be right. Please provide the full code where the constructor gets called by a static call!

Comment: Show your real code. What you're writing doesn't look correct.

Comment: How does the constructor look like, from what behaviour do you conclude that it runs?

Comment: "Show your code" means "show us all the code that is relevant to the situation". At the very least this includes the *class definition*, of the offending class, or at least the relevant function definitions inside the class definition.

Comment: I know the constructor is definitely being called, I added some test echo statements just to be sure. At least I know now that my understanding of how the constructor is supposed to work isn't wrong. I know its a weird issue but something is running my constructor when I make static calls. I'll have to keep looking...

Comment: The Photo::find_by_id static method is probably creating new Photo object.

Answer (score 26):

I see nothing that replicates your question.

See Demo: http://codepad.org/h2TMPYUV

Code:

```
class Foo {
    function __construct(){ 
        echo 'hi!';
    }
    static function bar(){
        return 'there';
    }
}

echo Foo::bar(); //output: "there"
```

Answer (score 6):

Assumption
PHP 5.x

Different goals, different path

1. create a new instance of a class (object)

   ```
   class myClassA
   {
      public $lv;

      public function __construct($par)
      {
          echo "Inside the constructor\n";
          $this->lv = $par;
      }
   }

   $a = new myClassA(11);
   $b = new myClassA(63);
   ```

   because we create a new object PHP calls:

   `__construct($par)`;

   of the new object, so:

   ```
   $a->lv == 11 

   $b->lv == 63
   ```
2. use a function  of a class

   ```
   class myClassB
   {
       public static $sv;

       public static function psf($par)
       {
           self::$sv = $par;
       }
   }

   myClassB::psf("Hello!");
   $rf = &myClassB::$sv;
   myClassB::psf("Hi.");
   ```

   now `$rf == "Hi."`

   function or variabiles must defined static to be accessed by `::`, no object is created calling "psf", the "class variable"  **sv** has only 1 instance inside the class.
3. use a singleton created by a Factory (myClassA is above)

   ```
   class myClassC
   {

       private static $singleton;

       public static function getInstance($par){

           if(is_null(self::$singleton)){

               self::$singleton = new myClassA($par);

           }

           return self::$singleton;

       }

   }

   $g = myClassC::getInstance("gino");
   echo "got G\n";

   $p = myClassC::getInstance("pino");
   echo "got P\n";
   ```

Using the factory (*getInstance*) the first time we construct a new object having *$par* set to **gino**.

Using the factory the second time *$singleton* has already a value that we return. No new object is created (no *__construct* is called, less memory & cpu is used).

The value of course is an object **instanceOf** myClassA and don't forget:

`myClassC::$singleton->lv == "gino"`

Pay attention to singletons:

[What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

By my answer I don't want promote/demote singleton. Simply from the words in the question, I made this calc:

"static"+"__construct"="singleton"!

Comment: you should have added a disclaimer regarding singletons ans tatic classes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

Comment: just to clarify   $g = myClassC::getInstance("gino"); and then  $p = myClassC::getInstance("pino"); , $g->lv and $p->lv values are the same = "gino". not gine and pino, because the constructor only run once!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my **workaround**:

I put method `construct()` in static class. Notice, it is different than `__construct()` which I use in regular classes.

Each class is in own file, so I lazy load that file on first use of class. This gives me event of first use of class.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

    include_once './' . $class . '.php';

    if (method_exists($class, 'construct')) {
        $class::construct();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to call `__construct` method, it will be  `new $class()`

Answer (score 0):

I define class properties as array in a static method and call them via the method. I'm not sure if it's the best solution or not but works great.

Example:

```
    class Foo
    {
      private static construct_method()
      {
        return [
          'one' => 1,
          'two' => 2
        ];
      }

      public static any_method()
      {
        return self::construct_method()['one'] + self::construct_method()['two'];
      }

    }

    echo Foo::any_method(); // 3
```