# How can I initiate session_start(); before every static method is called in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, static

I'm trying to learn OOP in PHP and I'm making a class with static methods.I tried the code below but the session_start(); will not work because the methods are static and no object is getting instantiated.Do you know any solution to this problem?

```
<?php

class Session{

    public function __construct(){
        session_start();
    }

    public static function set($data){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public static function get($key){
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }

}


Session::set(array(
    'mySessionKey' => 'mySessionValue'
));
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to manage your session. Each individual method shouldn't trigger a `session_start` call; your program should be organized so that the session is guaranteed to have started before any of these methods can be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight change to @Bluedayz answer ...

```
<?php

class Session {

    public static function set($data) {
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }

}


Session::set(array(
    'mySessionKey' => 'mySessionValue'
));
```

Comment: Does this actually make any difference?

Comment: thanks but is there any __construct like method for using with static methods?I mean I want the session_start(); to run before calling any of the static methods,is that possible?

Comment: Namely, code encapsulation, and keeps it in spec for what the OP wanted.

Comment: @user3407278 There is no way to do it for static methods. If you put it into a file though, you can simply add a `Session::init()` call to the bottom of where you create your Session class, and just require it once. Alternately, use a singleton pattern.

Comment: @user3407278, negative, `__constructors` are only called when you assign a variable that classes instantiation. [See the answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231198/php-constructors-and-static-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend you to add this to the top of the files where you operate with sessions:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
```

This starts your session if it did not already start.

Go to the php.net documentation to learn more about the super global **[`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :/ I know the procedural way of doing this.What I want is the solution  when using static methods!

Comment: @user3407278 What you want is the *wrong way* then. It's not the job of your class to start the session.